# Angular scope.$$isolateBinding.param exists but scope.param is undefined

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have a directive where my scope.param ("container object") is not defined...

JS

```
  app.directive('transferData', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        containerObject: '='
      }
    };
  }]);
```

HTML

```
<div transfer-data
             container-object="data"
             id="info"
             class="visually-hidden"
             data-account="23423"></div>
```

In my console, "scope.$$isolateBindings.containerObject" exists but scope.containerObject is undefined...so I can't access scope.containerObject in my link method...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add link function like this:
    `link: function(scope,elem, attr, ctrl) 
       {
        console.log('scope.$$isolateBindings.containerObject',
          scope.$$isolateBindings.containerObject)
        }`